# How to list all files in a folder which end with ".dat" with recent changes (datetime)

Tags: java, list

```
private static void listofRecentFile() {

        try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\DEV\\PrismaGateway\\Service\\"))) {

            List<Path> result = walk.filter(f -> f.toString().endsWith(".dat")).filter(Files::getLastModifiedTime).collect(Collectors.toList());

            result.forEach(System.out::println);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is I want to list all `.dat` file that just changed or recent changes, if in the folder there are 10 files but just 3 that I change that means it will show that 3 files only.

example:

```
|folder_a|   date   |<br>
|  a.dat |22/01/2020|<br>
|  b.dat |20/01/2020|<br>
|  c.dat |20/01/2020|<br>
|  d.dat |22/01/2020|<br>
|  e.dat |13/01/2020|<br>
|  f.txt |22/01/2020|<br>
```

the program will find `.dat` the file that has recent date change which is 22 January 2020 like below:

```
a.dat 22/01/2020 <br>
d.dat 22/01/2020
```

until now I just could list `.dat` file but still figuring out how to show the date/recent changes. can someone help me:")

Comment: Please do not write subjects (or anything else) is all caps.  It comes across as yelling at us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Object> result = walk.filter(f -> f.toString().endsWith(".dat")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                File file = new File(result.get(i).toString());
                for (Date date = day; !date.after(localDate); date = DateUtils.addDays(date, 1)) {
                    if (sdf.format(file.lastModified()).equals(sdf.format(date))) {
                        temp.append(file.getAbsolutePath() + ";");
                        totalDat++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

this could be more good just compare it and use temp string builder in it

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You to get things like the last access and last modification time, you need to load the files attributes, you could use this:

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(f.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);

out += "Creation Time      : " + attrs.creationTime() + "\n";
out += "Last Access Time   : " + attrs.lastAccessTime() + "\n";
out += "Last Modified Time : " + attrs.lastModifiedTime() + "\n";
out += "Is Directory       : " + attrs.isDirectory() + "\n";
out += "Is Other           : " + attrs.isOther() + "\n";
out += "Is Regular File    : " + attrs.isRegularFile() + "\n";
out += "Is Symbolic Link   : " + attrs.isSymbolicLink() + "\n";
out += "Size               : " + attrs.size() + "\n";

System.out.print(out);
```

Comment: No need for all the attributes;  [Files.getLastModifiedTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) is sufficient.

Comment: how to implement it on my code? i tried but seems wrong:( @VGR

Comment: @stephen090 Edit your question, and show us the code you attempted to run.

Comment: @VGR I already give an explanation about what I want to do, is it clear enough?

Comment: @stephen090 You said you tried to compare the files using their last modified time, but your question does not indicate any attempt at doing that.  There is no code which incorporates Matt’s suggestion or my suggestion.

Comment: @VGR I already tried adding filter `get last modified` like above but it is wrong so I don't know how to implement it on my method using walk filter.